# Java: fetching the list of file names in a directory inside a war file

Tags: java, servlets, war, file-listing

I have a web application in a servlet container.

How can I get the **list of files inside security folder** inside controller/servlet?

I tried something like this(which is not working):

```
File security_image_dir = new File("/beta/images/security/");
String security_images[] = security_image_dir.list();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way of accessing files within a web environment is [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). If you want to get a list of files then you can try [ServletContext.getResourcePaths()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I am actually looking for list of file names in a dir.